# How to find silverlight TreeViewItem by TextBlock?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0, treeview

I'm trying to select TreeViewItem on right mouse click. There is my XAML:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" ItemsSource ="{Binding DisplayedDocuments}"  
                    SelectedItemChanged="TreeView_SelectedItemChanged" IsEnabled="True"   
                    MouseRightButtonDown="treeView_MouseRightButtonDown">
        <sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DisplayedSubItems}">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource docImageConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock Width="5"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Caption}" 
                           MouseRightButtonDown="TextBlock_MouseRightButtonDown"/> 
             </StackPanel>  
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </sdk:TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

When I click on treeViewItem sometimes `TextBlock.MouseRightButtonDown` raises instead of `treeView.MouseRightButtonDown`. So, I want to get treeViewItem by TextBlock in TextBlock_MouseRightButtonDown. I've tried to get it this way:

```
    TextBlock docCaption = e.OriginalSource as TextBlock;
    StackPanel stackPanel = docCaption.Parent as StackPanel;
```

But stackPanel.Parent is null.

I've tried to find the control by name:

```
    TreeViewItem treeViewItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.FindName(docCaption.Text);
```

but it returns null.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Is there are a reason why you have two MouseRightButtonDown handlers?

Comment: First i've tried to show context menu for current (not selected) item on right click.

Comment: Yes, but do you need a MouseRightButtonDown on both TreeView and the TextBlock?

Comment: In any case, you can try using the VisualTreeHelper to walk up the tree till you find a treeview

Comment: I'm newbie in SL, can you explain me, how to use VisualTreeHelper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VisualTreeHelper to get the parent: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kmahone/archive/2009/03/29/visualtreehelper.aspx
http://miguelmadero.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/use-visualtreehelper-to-navigate.html